# Why can Rust not use const as literals?

Tags: rust, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```rust
const VERSION: &'static str = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");

fn main() {
    // OK
    println!("{}", "0.1.0");
    // OK
    println!("{}", env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"));
    // OK
    println!("{}", VERSION);
    // OK
    println!("0.1.0");
    // OK
    println!(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"));
    // error: format argument must be a string literal
    println!(VERSION);
}
```

The Rust doc of [const](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html) states that `const` creates a compile-time constant, and in [env!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) states that the `env!` macro creates a compile-time known `&'static str` value.

I'm curious, given that all these three values are known at compile-time with a fixed size, why can't they be used interchangeably? Why aren't they *semantically* equivalent?

Comment: Because macro-expansion happens before `const` processing, which is why the value of a `const` can be the result of a macro. This means `macro!(const_name)` receives an identifier, it does not and can not know that that's a const. The compiler will expand the const in the *result* of the macro expansion. I guess const could be performed at the same time as macro-expansion, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: The built-ins work a little funny so it might be a bug- a source file with just `include!(file!())` sends the compiler into infinite recursion.

Comment: `env!` expands to a string literal.

Comment: @Masklinn That does not matter, the "macro" can still work with the identifier since it is an intrinsic.

Comment: @Acorn macros can work with identifiers, `println!` does not. And the question is why `const` is not substitutable with literals in macros.

Comment: @Masklinn I didnt say that. I said the "macro" (it isnt one, thats the point) can work with the forwarded identifier and see that is it a comptime value and do whatever it needs to do, instead of forcing a literal. Your explanation is fine for user code, but doesnt really apply here.